# order by and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "specimens" ORDER BY distribution_sheet_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

and I have put:

```
<%=  Specimen.last(:order => :distribution_sheet_id).id  %>
```

I like to output 'limit 10' not limit 1.  I suppose its the .last, but can I express it in other way to limit 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Rails 3

```
<%= Specimen.limit(10).order("distribution_sheet_id").all %>
```

Please note that if you limit to more than 1 record, you can't call `#id` at the end because the result is an array.

To get all the ids

```
<%= Specimen.limit(10).order("distribution_sheet_id").map(&:id) %>
```

---

For Rails 2.3 use the old hash-based conditions.

```
<%= Specimen.all(:order => "distribution_sheet_id", :limit => 10) %>
```

and the same applies for the id

```
<%= Specimen.all(:order => "distribution_sheet_id", :limit => 10).map(&:id) %>
```

Here I'm using the `#to_sentence` method to join all ID. Adapt the code according to your use case.

```
<%= Specimen.all(:order => "distribution_sheet_id", :limit => 10).map(&:id).to_sentence %>
```

Comment: im getting undefined method `order' for #<Class:0xc9716a0>

Comment: I updated the answer. You might want to give a look at the `ActiveRecord` API to have a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: Im getting [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]

Comment: Actually im getting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.  I need the LAST 10

Comment: Change to descending order (`:order => 'distribution_sheet_id desc'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<% Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id desc', :limit => 10).each do |specimen| %>
  <li><%= specimen.id %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Im getting undefined method `order' for #<Class:0xc9716a0>

Comment: You're on Rails < 3.0. Instead use: `Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id', :limit => 10)`

Comment: its printing out #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #

Comment: print out the last 10 specimen ids using the last distribution_sheet_id

Comment: See new answer - should have the changes you need