# Find last order limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id', :limit => 10).each do |df| %>
  <%= df.id %>
<% end %>
```

This gives this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "specimens" ORDER BY distribution_sheet_id LIMIT 10
```

I need this:

```
SELECT * FROM "specimens" ORDER BY distribution_sheet_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

I'm using Rails < 3. Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [order by and limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537947/order-by-and-limit)

Comment: Sorry Ali, didn't realize you were < Rails 3

Comment: why don't you go and edit the question that Simone linked, seeing that it is about the same exact query.

Answer (score 3):

Add `DESC` to the end of your order value.

```
Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id DESC', :limit => 10)
```

Full example:

```
<% Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id DESC', :limit => 10).each do |df| %>
  <%= df.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: still getting [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]

Comment: Your query is now correct. You're seeing the # as those are the string representation of the object you are printing out.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `DESC`

```
Specimen.find(:all, :order => 'distribution_sheet_id DESC', :limit => 10).each do |df| %> <%= df.id
```

Comment: still getting [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]

Comment: Your query is now correct. You're seeing the `#` as those are the string representation of the object you are printing out.

Comment: Really? Did you restart Rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
Specimen.
  all(:order => 'distribution_sheet_id DESC', :limit => 10, :select => :id).
  map(:&id)
```